# jQuery code not working unless a plugin is connected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

Right, so I have two unrelated question:
1. I came across a code to create "read more"/"read less" buttons in long paragraphes. It seems simple enough, I've adjusted it to my needs... But for some reason it only works if I link the pages to another external JS plugin!
My HTML is linked to Jquery and a JS of my own design, but this one code won't work without that external plugin.
The thing is, that plugin is the tooltipsy plugin to create tooltips, it has nothing to do with that piece of code...
All other codes from the same JS and Jquery functions work perfectly except for that one, and it works perfectly with the tooltipsy plugin. Same code exactly:

```
var showChar = 200; 
var moretext = "...read more";
var lesstext = "...read less"; 
$(".more").each(function () {
    var content = $(this).html(); 
    if (content.length > showChar) { 

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar); 
        var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar); 
        var html = c + '<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>  <a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>'; 

        $(this).html(html); 
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function () { 
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext); 
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext); 
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle(); 
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
}); //End of code for toggeling more or less text.
```

I've tried putting an example in JSFiddle, but because the whole thing depends on external media on my computer (background pictures, fonts, etc.) it doesn't really display correctly.

2. For some reason, FireFox won't recognize local links in my site (i.e. I used "/JS.js" to indicate that the JS file is in the root folder. Chrome presents it without an issue, FireFox doesn't). Any idea why that is?

Thanx for the help!

Comment: Without seeing all the files you've included, my guess is that your code is using a jQuery dependency that the tooltipsy plugin includes, thus why it's working when you're including the plugin, but not working when it's not. 

I'd use the console view of your browser to inspect what scripts are, and aren't being included when you enable/disable the plugin. 

Do keep in mind, jquery doesn't come with all of it's components by default. A lot of it is packed into smaller packages, such as the UI etc. This might explain why your script is failing, because it's missing a dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all the files you've included, my guess is that your code is using a jQuery dependency that the tooltipsy plugin includes, thus why it's working when you're including the plugin, but not working when it's not.

I'd use the console view of your browser to inspect what scripts are, and aren't being included when you enable/disable the plugin.

Do keep in mind, jquery doesn't come with all of it's components by default. A lot of it is packed into smaller packages, such as the UI etc. This might explain why your script is failing, because it's missing a dependency.

*Edited converted comment to answer*

the toggle() command is part of the jquery ui, which as described above is an external component of jquery. You can easily hook in the jquery ui yourself, and this will fix your issue. You will want to load the component AFTER you load jquery, and it can be done the same way you'd load the jquery library.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

As for question #2, try using ./js/ as the path. Honestly though, don't use hard-coded links like that, because when you transition to a live server, it will likely break :)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying the Jquery file I use don't have the full range of Jquery functions? What good is it then?
Where can I find a full Jquery file or link? I tried several ones already (including a google hosted one from: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery
But nothing seems to work...

Comment: No, jquery doesn't come with a "full library", nor should it. Jquery is broken up into components, to keep it smaller, more modular and more maintainable. But the beauty of it all is, that you can pick and choose what components of it you need, based on what you need at the time. 

Think of it like a new car. Some people just need it to get from point a to b. They don't need a V8 engine, spoilers, digital speedometer etc, they just need 4 wheels an engine and seats. jQuery works on this same concept. You (the driver) decide what you need, and go from there.

Comment: Continuing with the above analogy, think of the initial jQuery library as the "Chasis, seats and engine". It's the bare basics you need to drive. What you need is the UI library, which you can find here: http://jqueryui.com/
as I mentioned above, make sure you include that library AFTER you load the initial jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have a conflict.
that happens when another lib uses the $ variable.

see : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: But the problem is when I DON'T use the other library! When I use it everything is fine, and it's just added to the Jquey and my JS...
So if there was a conflict between my JS and Jquery, it still wouldn't get resolved by adding yet ANOTHER library...
Also I doubt my JS and Jquery have a conflict, since that's way above my level and I basically used Jquety in every single one of my custom JS functions...

Comment: Hej, the other library uses jquery too? if so than i think you have an error in your jQuery link. if you add this to your header section, is the problem still there? <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: Not only did adding this instead of my Jquery file didn't work, it broke the rest of the Jquery commands as well...
And if you want to add it WITH the original file, I might as well add the tooltipsy one instead ;)
The point was to AVOID using another JS link in my pages.